# How to use DataBinding with AndroidX fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding

I'm using AndroidX library, my fragment is extend `androidx.fragment.app.fragment.Fragment`, it provides a construction where I can simply give layout ID and skip overriding `onCreateView` function like this:

```
class MyFragment (@LayoutRes layout:Int): Fragment(layout){
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //My View was created correctly.
    }
}
```

Now how I can retrieve the binding object using DataBindingUtil?
I tried  DataBindingUtil.getBinding(view) and  DataBindingUtil.findBinding(view) but they always return null. Is there any way without overriding `onCreateView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution. it's more simple than I thought :|

```
class MyFragment (@LayoutRes layout:Int): Fragment(layout){
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        MyFragmentBinding.bind(view)?.let{
           //Set binding data here.
        }
    }
}
```

read more here: https://zhuinden.medium.com/simple-one-liner-viewbinding-in-fragments-and-activities-with-kotlin-961430c6c07c